# UIImageView not displaying image - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation

I am using AVFramework to capture camera frames and I would like to process and display them in a UIImageView but am having some trouble.  I have the code:

```
// Delegate routine that is called when a sample buffer was written
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{ 
    //NSLog(@"Capturing\n");
    // Create a UIImage from the sample buffer data
    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];     

    NSLog(@"Image: %f %f\n", image.size.height, image.size.width);
    [imageView setImage:image];
}
```

However, it won't display. The correct size shows up in the `NSLog`, and when I put:

```
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SomethingElse.png"]];
```

in viewDidLoad, an image is displayed correctly (so I know the UIImageView is connected correctly).

Is there any reason this shouldn't work???  I am at a loss right now.

Cheers,
Brett

Comment: I should also add that when I put:
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SomethingElse.png"]]; 
in captureOutput: the image is still not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing this on the main thread? You can either use the main queue for the delegate (undesirable, because you're doing processing first) or:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    imageView.image = ...;
});
```

Comment: thank you, your response saved me what'd probably be a long time! I was capturing output on my own queue.

Answer (score 0):

Is imageView set correctly?  If imageView is actually nil, your call to `[imageView setImage:image];` will silently do nothing.

Comment: Yup, when I NSLog(@"%@", imageView); I can see the address, CALayer address, etc. So looks like it is not nil.

Comment: More specifically: the NSLog of imageView looks like: 
<UIImageView: 0x130c50; frame = (0 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x12f730>>